# Can page.js work without a web server?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to make client side routing for an html5 app where the client will download a zipped folder containing a single html file and javascript. I looked into page.js for the routing but it doesn't seem to work without a server.... how come? I get caught either in a indefinite loop or at a wrong page.

My routing looks like this:

```
page ('/help'){
    openPage('help');
}
```

obviously there is no help.html in the directory so it returns a 404.

If I can't use page.js for routing what else should I use... angular.js?